# Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m : user agent stylesheet not showing display property

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm running a simple page to determine the display property of a strong tag :

```
<p>This is a line of text, this is <strong>bold</strong></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grimmus/5hHQ2/1/show/

When i inspect the strong element in the styles tab it shows the font-weight property but not display. If i go into computed properties i can see display:inline.

I am confused why the styles tab does not show this property. Has something changed in the latest version of Chrome dev tools ? Thanks.

[image: Styles tab]

[image]

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/html.css&l=988 does not seem to contain the "display: inline" property. Are you sure you had seen it before?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It just feels like something has changed with the latest release. I thought i could always see the display property values from the styles tab. I guess i'm wrong !